# Diophantine equation $x^2 + 32x = y^3$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

I am trying to find all solutions to the Diophantine equation $x^2 + 32x = y^3$.

I think that the first step is to factorise: $x(x+32)=y^3$.

If $x$ is odd, then $x+32$ is also odd. The common divisors of $x$ and $x+32$ must divide 32, and since all the divisors of 32 are even except 1, then we must have gcd$(x,x+32)=1$. Therefore $x$ and $x+32$ are cubes, and since there are no cubes which are 32 apart, then there are no solutions when $x$ is odd.

I am stuck on what to do when $x$ is even. Is the same approach the best way to do it, i.e. consider all the possible common divisors when $x$ is even? I don't see how to proceed from this point.

Comment: If $x$ is even, $x=2k$, then $4k^2+64k=y^3$ and you have $y$ even also, so can factor some power of 2 out of the whole equation. See what happens if you keep doing this... just a thought.

Comment: @coffeemath The eqation is no homogeneous, so the fact that $k$ and $y$ are not relatively prime doesn't give you an obvious descent.

Comment: Note that the GCD of $k$ and $k+64$ is a divisor of $64$, that is, a power of $2$. 

Factoring out the powers of $2$ from $k$ and $k+64$ and you have to get a perfect cube in both cases. That is, if $k=2^\alpha a$ and $k+64=2^\beta b$ where $a,b$ are odd and relatively prime, so $a,b$ must be perfect cubes, and $\alpha+\beta$ must be a multiple of $3$. We also know that $\min(\alpha,\beta)\leq 6$.

Probably can work from there.

Comment: @user50229 Okay, I'll repost that comment. This equation is the same as $(k+16)^2 = y^2 + 256$.

Comment: And replace every occurrence of $64$ in my above comment with $32$ :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $z = x + 16$.  Then we have $(z-16)(z+16) = y^3$.

**Case A:**
If $z-16$ and $z+16$ are coprime, each must be a cube, and then we have two cubes whose difference is $32$. As the difference between cubes increases fairly fast, it is easy to check that there are no such cubes. $[3^3 - 2^3 = 19, 4^3 - 3^3 = 37, \cdots]$.

**Case B:**
If $z-16$ and $z+16$ share a factor $k > 1$, as $\gcd(z-16, z+16) = \gcd(32, z + 16),$ we must have $k \mid 32$.  It is easy to see that $k$ must be the highest power of $2$ which divides either of $z-16$ or $z+16$, *unless one of them is zero*.

Assume first that neither of $z-16$ or $z+16$ are zero.  Then
$k^2 \mid LHS \implies k^2 \mid y^3 \implies k = 8$, a perfect cube, as there is no other factor of $2$ in the LHS.  Let $u = \dfrac{z}{8}$ in that case, and we have $(u-2)(u+2) = v^3$ as the equation now.  Now $u-2$ and $u+2$ must be coprime and hence cubes themselves. So we have two cubes whose difference is $4$.  Easy to verify such cubes do not exist.

Hence the only case remaining is when either $z-16=0$ or $z+16=0$.  In both options, we have obvious solutions with $y=0$, corresponding to $x = 0$ or $x = -32$.

Comment: No, it doesn't sorry.. (I rewrite the previous comment here)
Define $\upsilon_2(m)$ the $2$-adic valuation of $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then following your notation $k=\text{gcd}(z+16,z-16)\mid 32$, so $k=2^a$, with $a=\upsilon_2(k)$ such that $1\le a\le 5$. Now the condition $k^2 \mid y^3$ is not equivalent to $2a=\upsilon_2(y^3)$ but $$2a\le \upsilon_2(y^3)\text{ i.e. } a\le \lfloor \frac{3}{2} \upsilon_2(y) \rfloor .$$

I hope you got my point now..

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti  OK.  Let me try again, and would appreciate if you say either you agree with all thats in the comment but your issue is with something else, or where you specifically disagree in the comment.
$$---$$
Let $a , b$ be the $2$-adic valuations of $z-16$ and $z+16$, ordered s.t. $a \ge b$.  
Given $k > 1$ is $\gcd(v-16, v+16)$, then $$1 \le v_2(k) = b \le 5.$$  

Now if $a \le 5$, we have $a = b = v_2(k)$, so $v_2(k) \equiv 0 \mod 3$ from the cube, and I assume the rest follows.

Comment: Continuing, 
only other possibility is $a > 5$, giving $b = 5$.  
So $z + 16 = 32u$ and $z - 16 = 32 v$,  and $u - v = 1$.
But $$(32v) 32(v+1) = y^3  \implies 2 v(v+1) = w^3.$$  
As consecutive numbers cannot share prime factors, this means one among $v$ or $(v+1)$ is a cube and the other is $4$ times a cube.  This is not possible unless one of them is zero.  If this part was your issue, perhaps the italics in my answer was insufficient and I should have detailed more.

Comment: On this last bit though on reflection, while seemed easy, it is not trivial to show that consecutive numbers cannot be a cube and four times a cube.  One needs to solve a cubic Pell equation, or take your approach

Comment: I am glad, you realized the problem now ;)

Comment: Sadly, there is still a mistake :/ the equation $$2v(v+1)=w^3\text{ with }2\mid v+1$$ implies only that $v$ is a cube such that $v\mid w^3$, i.e. $$2(v+1)=\left(\frac{w}{\sqrt[3]{v}}\right)^3.$$

In practice we know that $\text{rad}(v) \mid \text{rad}(w)$ but we cannot conclude that $v\mid w$..

Anyway, I like that you listen all comments, you have my thumb up too, although I still didnt realize why it should be useful :)

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti Ah.. guess we have to bother Euler after all.  This is getting too long, so stopping for now and deleting diverting comments.  Thanks for the fine tooth comb though, didn't realise the bits being skipped, relying on what seemed obvious.

Comment: That's ok :) Cheers Macavity!

Answer (score 2):

If $2\nmid x$ then $x$ and $x+32$ need to be both cubes, that is impossible. So there exist $x_1,y_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x=2x_1$, $y=2y_1$, and we get $$x_1(x_1+16)=2y_1^3$$
If $2\nmid x_1$ then $2\nmid x_1+16$, so there exists $x_2 \in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $x_1=2x_2$. But then $2\mid \text{gcd}(x_1,x_1+16)$, implying that $4\mid 2y_1^3$, i.e. there exists $y_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $y_1=2y_2$. Substituing we get $$x_2(x_2+8)=4y_2^3.$$
Going ahead at the same way, we get that $2\mid x_2$, setting $x_2=2x_3$ for some $x_3 \in \mathbb{Z}$ we get $$x_3(x_3+4)=y_2^3.$$ If $2\nmid x_3$ then $2\nmid x_3y_2(x_3+4)$, and in particular $x_3$ and $x_3+4$ have to be both cubes of some integers, and that's again impossible. So by force $2\mid x_3$, implying that $2\mid y_2$, i.e. there exist $x_4,y_4$ such that $x_3=2x_4$, $y_2=2y_4$. Now we get $$x_4(x_4+2)=2y_4^3;$$ as before $2\mid \text{gcd}(x_4,y_4)$, we set $x_4=2x_5, y_4=2y_5$ and we get $$x_5(x_5+1)=4y_5^3$$
To ease finally the notation, set $\alpha=2x_5-1$ and $\beta=2y_5$: the above equation is exactly equivalent to $$\alpha^2-1=2\beta^3, \text{ with }\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{Z}.$$
Since $2\nmid \alpha$ then $2=\text{gcd}(\alpha+1,\alpha-1)$. So, we have exactly two cases.

**Case 1.**
$\alpha+1=2a^3, \alpha-1=b^3$ for some integers $a,b$. $b$ has to be even, so that $$\left(2\frac{a}{b}\right)^3+\left(-\frac{2}{b}\right)^3=4.$$

**Case 2.**
$\alpha+1=c^3, \alpha-1=2d^3$ for some integers $c,d$. $c$ has to be even, so that $$\left(2\frac{d}{c}\right)^3+\left(\frac{2}{c}\right)^3=4.$$

[Thanks to Yimin for the correction: we have to rule out cases $b=0$ and $c=0$ before dividing all the remaining part, from which we obtain exactly the two trivial solution $x=0$ and $x=-32$]

In both cases we should get a rational solution $(X,Y) \in \mathbb{Q}^2$ to the equation $$X^3+Y^3=4.(*)$$

Now, both Euler (see Algebra, 2, 1770, Art.247) and Dirichlet (see Werke, II, Anhang, 352-3) proved by descent that (*) has no rational solutions.

Comment: see here http://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment, you need more reputation. So ANSWER SOME questions, and obtain more reputation.

Comment: @Paolo Is your conclusion then that there are no solutions? This is plainly wrong as you can see that $x=-32, y=0$ is a solution by inspection.

Comment: Case 1: $b$ can be zero. The rest are good.

Comment: Also in case 2 $c$ can be zero, from which we obtain the other solution $x=-32$; except that (I am going to edit it, thank you), yes, there are no other solutions :)

Answer (score 2):

I will leave it to others to find an elementary proof, but I just wanted to say that this equation defines an elliptic curve $E:x^2+32x=y^3$ (usually the so-called Weierstrass equation would be written $y^2+32y=x^3$, but that doesn't matter). The Mordell-Weil theorem states that the set of rational points is a finitely generated abelian group, so
$$E(\mathbb{Q})\cong T_E \times \mathbb{Z}^{R_E},$$
where $T_E$ is a finite subgroup, and $R_E\geq 0$ is called the rank of the elliptic curve. There are methods to calculate $T_E$ and $R_E$ (such as the Nagell-Lutz theorem, or the method of $2$-descent), and these methods are implemented in software such as Sage and Magma. In this case:
$$T_E=\{\mathcal{O},(0,0),(-32,0)\}\cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z},$$
where $\mathcal{O}$ is the *point at infinity* with projective coordinates $[1,0,0]$, and $R_E=0$. So there are no other rational or integral points other than $(0,0)$ and $(-32,0)$.

I calculated the torsion and rank using [the online Magma calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/):

> E:=EllipticCurve([0,0,32,0,0]);
>
> Rank(E);
>
> TorsionSubgroup(E);